# WCF service access error on the server

Tags: wcf

I have a wcf service that is hosted on a server. I can browse to the service without a problem from my local computer. I cannot browse to the service using the same url from the server. Any ideas as to why this would happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. The domain that the service was hosted on was using an IPv6 address in the bindings in IIS. After I changed that to use the wildcard for an IP address (I can do that since there are no other sites on the server) everything worked fine.